# Google Sheets; get a row based on the first column, then use the second column?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

So, let's say column A is 'Type', something like x or y.
Column B is a duration.

I want to select all rows where A = x, and add them together to get the total duration for 'x' rows.

So I can obtain all of the correct rows like this:

```
=QUERY(LIST!A:Z, "SELECT A where A = 'X'")
```

Now how do I get the corresponding B value for that row?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's pretty simple to do, using the [SUMIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093583) function:

```
=SUMIF(A:A, "x", B:B)
```

It will sum the values of the `B:B` range, only when the corresponding cell in `A:A` has a value of `x`.

Comment: This does what I need. Delightfully simple. I always over-complicate things. Thank you.